How do I return a CSS/JS with Crow C++?
I am trying to return a load.css file along with index.html, but it gives me a 404 error. I tried manually reading the file and setting res.body == load.css data, but that would make the request stuck on loading.
What am I doing wrong?
void foo() {
    crow::SimpleApp app;
    crow::mustache::set_global_base("/home/cereza/testing/src/frontend/src/");

    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/") ([] () {
        auto page = crow::mustache::load("html/index.html");
        return page.render();
    });

    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/style/load.css") ([] () {
        crow::response res;
        res.set_static_file_info("style/load.css");
        return res;
    });
}

I already tried changing paths and testing if files are being read or not.

You don't need to make a separate route for JS and CSS files. These are "static" files that your site serves and they go in a special folder called "static".
Your project structure should look something like this:
└── appRoot/
    ├── static/
    │   ├── jsFile1.js
    │   ├── jsFile2.js
    │   ├── cssFile1.css
    │   └── cssFile2.css
    ├── templates/
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── page2.html
    ├── server.cpp
    └── otherCppFile.cpp

Remove the extra route from your server:
int main() {
    crow::SimpleApp app;
    crow::mustache::set_global_base("/home/cereza/testing/src/frontend/src/");

    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/") ([] () {
        auto page = crow::mustache::load("index.html");
        return page.render();
    });
}

And then in your index.html file, you can include the js and css like normal:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cssFile1.css">
<script src="/static/jsFile1.js"></script>

See static files from the Crow docs.
